# TFS : Web access not up to date

Tags: templates, tfs, tfs-power-tools, defects

I'm using TFS 2013, Visual Studio 2013 
I need special fields in my defects. so  I've done some modifications on the defects template using power tools.

My changes are well there in Visual studio. but my users can't see anything in webaccess.

tried to restart IIS, clearing cache, restarting the collection ... nothing changes.

Any Help please?

Comment: Any chance your Work Item has multiple form definitions? One for Web and one for Windows?

Comment: What customization did you do, most of the basic ones, add a field, change location, etc should replicate automatically.  If you have a new work item control (hope not) then it may work on you machine (maybe not others) and will not work on the web unless deployed to the TFS AT.